# How can make a function which works just some platform?

Tags: swift

I can use #if directly in my codes and it works just fine, however I want make a reusable function and call it in other places as well, I made this function:

```
func runOniOS(action: () -> Void) {
#if os(iOS)
    action()
#endif
}
```

And I am using it in my multi platform project for macOS like this:

```
runOniOS(action: {
    let redColor: UIColor = .red
})
```

But Xcode take it as an error and say:

> Cannot find type 'UIColor' in scope

How can I make a reusable function?

Comment: You can't "hide" the `#if` like this. The closure has to be able to compile on its own, regardless of whether or not `funOniOS` eventually calls it or not.

Comment: In that case `#if` is the only way for such a works? Do we got other ways than using `#if` but with same results?

Comment: Looks like you need to import UIKit, or SwiftUI if you're using that.

Comment: @DanO'Leary: It is not about what you said. it is something else.

Comment: @ioscoder I don't understand your question, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Alexander: I fully understand about your first comment, just asked if there is any other option to get the same results that we could get from #if but having freedom to hide them in function.

Comment: @ioscoder Not really. Your closure needs to be compilable, even outside of an iOS target, unless you wrap it in `#if os(iOS)` as well. Alternatively, you can make a typealias with a conditional value that's either `NSColor` or `UIColor` depending on the platform. Then you can use `YourColor.red` and have it work on both platforms